# Removing blog title from blog posts in blogger

Tags: blogs, title, blogger, blogspot

I'm unable to remove my blog title from my post title in my blogger blogspot. I've tried,

```
.post-title.entry-title {
display: none;
}
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you share your blog's URL where you are facing this issue

Comment: http://englishmoviesonline.blogspot.com/
how long does it takes for webmaster to update it ???

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about post title where you want to remove **home page title** after **post title** than:

replace `<title>` to `</title>` with (located under the `<head>` tag)

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title> 
<b:else/>
<title><data:blog.pageName/></title>
</b:if>
```

Comment: here is how its showing on my template
    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
    <b:else/>
    <title><data:blog.pageName/> - <data:blog.title/></title>
    </b:if>
    <meta content='Your Blog Description here!' name='description'/>

Or perhaps if anyone could tell me how long does it takes for google webmasters to update it in the search engine

Comment: you have to replace title to title with the above coding to show only title in index posts

Comment: i already had that coding in there.
i'm just waiting for the webmasters to update

Answer (score 0):

go to `<b:includable id='title'>` then add `<!--` and `-->` below `<b:else/>`

or, you can add inline css inside heading-1, as follows:

```
<h1 class='' style='display:none; visibility:hidden;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove it by css. You can add following css code.

```
.post h1 {
   display: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the top most section you will this line of code

```
<data:blog.title/>
```

and close to it you will find this code

```
<data:blog.pageName/>
```

remove  and save your template

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the "Edit HTML" button and select "Ok."
   2.widget id='Header1' locked='true' to locked='false'
2. Select "Layout" from the left column and click "Edit" under the Header element.
3. Remove the title or just click "Remove" button from the footer.
4. Save your template by clicking on "Save Arrangement."